# Automatically use the directory as the project name in CMake

Tags: cmake

I'm fairly new at using CMake to manage my build system, so if I'm being stupid and this is a bad idea, please let me know.

I'd like to be able to set up my cmakelists.txt file so that when I do

```
project( ... )
```

the name of the directory becomes the project name automatically.  I want to do this because I find it convenient to be able to copy the entire directory of one project as the starting point of another.  However, though I always rename the directory to something meaningful, I often forget to change the `project(name)` line of the cmakelists.txt file, and then I end up with multiple projects open in my build environment with the same name, which gets confusing.

Ideally, if there are spaces in the directory name they'd be replaced by underscores.

Can CMake do this? And is it a bad idea for some reason I'm not seeing?

Comment: "_is it a bad idea for some reason I'm not seeing?_" If you intend for your project to be used by others, then it _can_ lead to unexpected and possibly annoying things happening for your users. For example [`FetchContent`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html) fetches to a directory with a configurable name (see the `SOURCE_DIR` argument of `ExternalProject`), and by default, fetches the source to a directory named with the _user-chosen_ name of the thing to fetch, suffixed with "`-src`".

Comment: There are variables that get defined based on project name, such as [`<PROJECT_NAME>_VERSION`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PROJECT-NAME_VERSION.html) and friends, [`<PROJECT_NAME>_SOURCE_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PROJECT-NAME_SOURCE_DIR.html), [`<PROJECT_NAME>_BINARY_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PROJECT-NAME_BINARY_DIR.html), and so on. It could be annoying to people wanting to write things using those variables if they don't have a predictable name.

Comment: As you can see in the answer post, it takes three lines of CMake to get what you ask for, and only one line to do things the normal and expected way. I'd just do it the normal and expected way.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding the following to the start of your CMakeLists.txt:

```
get_filename_component(ProjectId ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} NAME)
string(REPLACE " " "_" ProjectId ${ProjectId})
project(${ProjectId})
```

I don't see a problem with doing this for throwaway projects, although I guess production projects would normally have a predefined name which would be set explicitly in the `project` command.

When you mention that you "copy the entire directory of one project as the starting point of another", I assume you don't include the build tree when you copy?  CMake [isn't really able to handle the build tree being moved](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.9/cmake.html#variable:CMAKE_USE_RELATIVE_PATHS).

Comment: You should use ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} instead of ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} overwise you get an error if you have a directory inside another directory.
Look at the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662497/in-cmake-what-is-the-difference-between-cmake-current-source-dir-and-cmake-curr

Comment: @Maks - A fair point, although [`CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR.html) is more appropriate than [`CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR.html) since it refers to the directory containing the CMakeLists.txt being processed for the current project, whereas `...LIST_DIR` will change with `include` calls.

Comment: This is useful to me when I have 2-3 different branches checked out in different working trees and want to switch among them in QtCreator - e.g., to compare/contrast source and execution.  It then also lets me deposit the builds in different locations programatically based on project name, even though they all should have had the same project name.  Locally, I might concatenate the official project name with my directory name...

Answer (score 4):

I think CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR more suitable for this case

```
get_filename_component(ProjectId ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} NAME)
string(REPLACE " " "_" ProjectId ${ProjectId})
project(${ProjectId} C CXX)
```

Answer (score 4):

Newer CMake (3.20+) supersedes get_filename_component with cmake_path:

```
cmake_path(GET CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR FILENAME ProjectName)   
string(REPLACE " " "_" ProjectId ${ProjectName})
project(${ProjectName})
```