# Difference between CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR and CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR

Tags: cmake

### From the Wiki:

**CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR**
this is the directory where the currently processed CMakeLists.txt is located in

**CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR** 
(since 2.8.3) this is the directory of the listfile currently being processed.

### From the Docs:

**CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR:** The path to the source directory currently being processed.
This the full path to the source directory that is currently being processed by cmake.

**CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR:** Full directory of the listfile currently being processed.
As CMake processes the listfiles in your project this variable will always be set to the directory where the listfile which is currently being processed (CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE) is located. The value has dynamic scope. When CMake starts processing commands in a source file it sets this variable to the directory where this file is located. When CMake finishes processing commands from the file it restores the previous value. Therefore the value of the variable inside a macro or function is the directory of the file invoking the bottom-most entry on the call stack, not the directory of the file containing the macro or function definition.

Under what circumstances would these variables hold different values?

Comment: And also how they differ from simple and nice `./`?

Comment: CMake and its documentation are utterly confusing

Comment: And what confuses me most is "Therefore the value of the variable inside a macro or function is the directory of the file invoking the bottom-most entry on the call stack, not the directory of the file containing the macro or function definition." I'm totally lost, what it means by that "the bottom of the call stack"? People can easily take it that CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR should be the dir containing the topmost CMakeLists.txt.

Answer (score 222, accepted):

The variables [`CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR.html) and [`CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR.html) may refer to different directories for a CMake list file that is included by another  file with the [include](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include.html) command. E.g., if a `CMakeLists.txt` is present in a directory `project` and contains the following directive

```
include(src/CMakeLists.txt)
```

then while `src/CMakeLists.txt` is being processed `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` will refer to `project/src` whereas `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` still points to the outer directory `project`.

`CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` comes in handy, when you need to locate resource files like template files or batch scripts that are located next to the `CMakeLists.txt` file currently being processed.

---

<sub>Note: When using the `add_subdirectory()` command rather than `include()`, the behavior is different, and when `src/CMakeLists.txt` is being processed, both variables will point to `project/src`.</sub>

Comment: +1. I would just add that `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` changes with every file you `include()`; it doesn't have to be called `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: [Good discussion here](https://crascit.com/2016/01/31/enhanced-source-file-handling-with-target_sources/) on how to effectively use `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` and `include(...)` in your projects.

Comment: Easily confused because `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` is more similar to `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` than the docs imply.

Comment: And with `add_subdirectory()`? Will both variables point to the folder?

Comment: @einpoklum Yes, they are. You can test it with `message(STATUS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} = ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")`.

Comment: So, `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` is more certain to be the directory containing the file where this variable is written than `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` ?

Answer (score 41):

**Definitions**

`CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`: Topmost folder(source directory) that contains a CMakeList.txt file. The value never changes in different scopes.

`PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR`: The nearest folder that contains CMakeList.txt file, with its own scope, that contains project() command.

`CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`: The nearest folder that contains CMakeList.txt file with its own scope. (File do not need to contain project() command)

`CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR`: The folder that contains currently processed CMakeList.txt or .cmake file.

What I mean by its own scope is related to scoping rules. While include(file) command is not creating a new scope, add_subdirectory is creating a new scope which affects the PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR and CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR values.

**Example**

Let project structure be like below:

```
A/
=> CMakeList.txt
=> B/
   => CMakeList.txt
```

and let us assume we are printing all cmake variables by putting message command to CMakeList.txt file in subfolder B.

- If CMakeList.txt in folder A contains a line include("B/CMakeList.txt"), then

`CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` will be source directory which is "path to project/A".

`PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` will be "path to project/A", because include command does not create a new scope and the nearest CMakeList.txt file that has its own scope and contains project command is in folder A.

`CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` will be "path to project/A", because include command does not create a new scope and the nearest CMakeList.txt file that has its own scope is in folder A.

`CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` will be "path to project/A/B", because currently processed file is in subfolder B.

- If CMakeList.txt contains a line add_subdirectory("./B"), then

`CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` will be source directory which is "path to project/A".

`PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` will be "path to project/A/B", because add_subdirectory command creates a new scope and the nearest CMakeList.txt file that has its own scope and contains project command is in subfolder B.

`CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` will be "path to project/A/B", because add_subdirectory command creates a new scope and the nearest CMakeList.txt file that has its own scope is in subfolder B.

`CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` will be "path to project/A/B", because currently processed file is in subfolder B.

**Reference**: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/Useful-Variables

Comment: I found your answers here incredibly useful for solving my problem, thanks for sharing!

Comment: CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR does not contain the current .cmake.