# Android NDK Cmake default root directory when adding prebuilt libraries

Tags: android, android-ndk, cmake

In the following snippet from the Google tutorial  *'Add C and C++ Code to Your Project'*

In the section *'Add other prebuilt libraries'*

```
add_library(...)
set_target_properties( # Specifies the target library.
                       imported-lib

                       # Specifies the parameter you want to define.
                       PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION

                       # Provides the path to the library you want to import.
                       imported-lib/src/${ANDROID_ABI}/libimported-lib.so )
```

source: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

What is the implicit root directory associated with `imported-lib/src/${ANDROID_ABI}/libimported-lib.so` ?

My 1st guess was that it was `project/app/` i.e. the directory where `CMakeLists.txt` resides, but experimentation suggests this is not the case. I get link errors saying the functions in the shared library cannot be found when I make this assumption.

Update:

Further to Tsyvarev s help I've realised the error is not from `set_target_properties()` but `target_link_libraries()`

`set_target_properties()` does seem to use `project/app` as its root

but `target_link_libraries()` doesn't. If I assume `project/app` as the root for my prebuilt shared library location then my project build fails. If I specify the full path, i.e. from `/home/me/...etc./etc./mylib.so` then it does work.

The error message in the 1st instance is:

```
/home/me/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -llibs/armeabi-v7a/libmylib.so
```

maybe the root dir in this instance is that in which `ld` is located?

Comment: `I get link errors saying the functions in the shared library cannot be found when I make this assumption.` - This error means that your shared library doesn't define given functions. Or that you forgot to link with that library (using `target_link_libraries`). If linker fails to find the library for link with, then it emits **other error**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation for [IMPORTED_LOCATION](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_LOCATION.html) property, it should be explicitely specified as a **full path**:

> Full path to the main file on disk for an IMPORTED target.

If you want this path to be under *current source directory*, prepend it with `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/`.

---

Specifying *relative* path is just an **undefined behavior**.

In your case CMake simply passes the path to the linker (that is, linker searches it under system library directories and ones added with `link_directories()` command). But this behavior, as *non-documented*, may be changed in the future at any time.

Comment: current source dir being that which CMakeLists.txt resides in. See related question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662497/in-cmake-what-is-the-difference-between-cmake-current-source-dir-and-cmake-curr

Comment: `Specifying relative path is just an undefined behavior.` This is really true! I was following this tutorial http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=52182 and I had to replace `src/main/cpp/main.cpp` with `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp`.

Comment: @FonzTech: Relative paths to the source files in `add_library` or `add_executable` are perfectly acceptible: CMake automatically transforms them to the absolute paths relative to the current source or binary directory. But `IMPORTED_LOCATION` property should be an absolute path: this path isn't automatically translated to the absolute.

Comment: I tried playing with paths and now I managed to add my cpp files through relative paths. Anyway, your answer helped me figuring out the problem.