# How can I set CMAKE_MODULE_PATH for doing regular and out-of-source builds in CMake?

Tags: cmake

I have a line like this in my `CMakeLists.txt`

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "cmake")
```

This is so that some custom libraries can be found with a directory tree that looks like this:

```
CMakeLists.txt
cmake/
|-- FindSomeLibrary.cmake
|-- FindAnotherLibrary.cmake
```

Normally I build simply like this:

```
cmake .
```

Which works fine. However, I want to provide a debug and release build using a script like this:

```
mkdir release
cd release
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../
```

However, now it cannot find the cmake modules.

Is there a way to set `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` such that it works for both in-source and out-of-source builds?

Comment: I don't know a very good solution. You could `set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "cmake" PARENT_SCOPE)` to set it in the parent scope, but that's not that nice

Comment: Thanks @Justin, just curious what's "not nice" about it?

Comment: Some things which are not nice about it: if it's hidden by two `add_subdirectory`s (e.g. `add_subdirectory(external)`, which does `add_subdirectory(my_library)`), the outermost scope won't see it.

Comment: Also I get this when I tried it: `Cannot set "CMAKE_MODULE_PATH": current scope has no parent.`

Comment: You could combine it with this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25199677/1896169

Comment: In both build scenarios I get `Parent doesn't have a scope` (eg. `hasParent` is false)

Comment: Exactly, so only set in the parent scope when there is a parent

Comment: `set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)` ? __Always__ use paths relative to CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR.

Comment: Ha, I was just trying that and it worked. Please post and I will accept your answer.

Comment: Actually I ended up using `set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake")`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As proposed in the comments:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)
```

and always try to set all paths relative to some CMAKE_* directory. That way you will miss many errors. ; )

As `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` is a list, so it's better to use:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
```

Comment: Also for anyone else wondering, there could be uses for using `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` or `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662497/difference-between-cmake-current-source-dir-and-cmake-current-list-dir#15667036

Answer (score 0):

Just to remember for myself (in modern cmake 3.xx):

1. if you need to `include(some_file_module)` add to `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`
2. if you need to `find_package(package CONFIG REQUIRED)` add to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`

example:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake")
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake")
```