# Cant change version of Boost when building in QT Creator

Tags: c++, boost, build, qt-creator

Im trying to build [Fritzing](https://github.com/fritzing/fritzing-app) using the instructions here:
https://github.com/fritzing/fritzing-app/wiki/1.-Building-Fritzing

Here:
https://siytek.com/build-fritzing-windows/

And here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=deyyxNkQPSM

They are basically the same and produces the same error when I building or runnin it in QT creater 11.0.2

```
Checking for boost... no
Project MESSAGE: Boost 1.54 has a bug in a function that Fritzing uses, so download or install some other version
Project ERROR: Easiest to copy the Boost library to ..., so that you have .../boost_1_xx_0
```

I have done what the errormessage suggested and put Boost library as sibling to the others but still the same error.

My folderstructure looks like this:
[image]

**I am using**

- libgit2-0.28.5
- boost_1_80_0
- latest version of Fritzing from github

How can I change version of Boost?

**Operating System:**
Windows 10

**UPDATE**

using boost 1.81.0 solved it. However now I got another bug.

```
Project MESSAGE: Using fritzing ngspice detect script.
Project ERROR: ngspice not found in C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/Fritzing/source/ngspice-40
```

I did put ngspice in that folder it suggested and that worked.

**UPDATE 2**
I now got a new bug:
:-1: error: Project ERROR: quazip include path not found in C:/include/quazip

I download quazip and did run it in another instance of Qt Creater and configure the project. I then get errormessages ...

```
C:\Program Files\cmake-3.18.0-rc2-win64-x64\share\cmake-3.18\Modules\FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:165: error: Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR) C:/Program Files/cmake-3.18.0-rc2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:458 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE) C:/Program Files/cmake-3.18.0-rc2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindZLIB.cmake:115 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS) CMakeLists.txt:141 (find_package)
```

Comment: Take look at these: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3016498/4165552 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/52730517/4165552 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/60208839/4165552

Comment: Looks like it is finding boost but it's not compiling for some reason, the version message is just a generic error, it doesn't necessarily mean you have the wrong version https://github.com/fritzing/fritzing-app/blob/6b14cfe9016652e47b5da53ce3d199175736e43e/pri/boostdetect.pri#L45

Comment: What is the contents of your `boost_1_82_0` directory? Is it an installation of boost with an `include` subdirectory and the compiled libraries or is it the boost source code?

Comment: @pptaszni they're not using cmake

Comment: @AlanBirtles it is this one: https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_82_0.html

Comment: looks like the current version only looks for boost 1.81.0: https://github.com/fritzing/fritzing-app/commit/35da391ac6d6cb86667c3a338d6ab1e9616e65ad, try setting `boost_root` as an environment variable

Comment: thanks. This was the answer. When I changed to 1.81.0 it worked again! Thanks!

Comment: However now I got a new bug as in the update above:
`Project MESSAGE: Using fritzing ngspice detect script.
Project ERROR: ngspice not found in C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/Fritzing/source/ngspice-40`

Comment: Ok a new bug:
:-1: error: Project ERROR: quazip include path not found in C:/include/quazip

I download quazip and did run it in another instance of Qt Creater and configure the project. I then get errormessages ...

Comment: `C:\Program Files\cmake-3.18.0-rc2-win64-x64\share\cmake-3.18\Modules\FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:165: error: Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR) C:/Program Files/cmake-3.18.0-rc2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:458 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE) C:/Program Files/cmake-3.18.0-rc2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindZLIB.cmake:115 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS) CMakeLists.txt:141 (find_package)`