# get makefile parameter from folder name

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile, cmake

I am trying to create a makefile for an OpenCV project. The template looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( DisplayImage )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( DisplayImage DisplayImage.cpp )
target_link_libraries( DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Is there any way to replace the hardcoded string `DisplayImage` with the name of the folder? My goal is to have each project in a folder and just drop in a makefile.

Comment: Just write a little script that generates that CMakeLists.txt file. That's going to make it both convenient, while having the names explicit (I prefer that myself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use cmake method: [get_filename_component](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3Aget_filename_component), to extract the parent directory and place it whereever you require:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

get_filename_component(PARENT_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} NAME)
project( ${PARENT_DIR} )

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

# If you want to change the executable name as well
add_executable( ${PARENT_DIR} DisplayImage.cpp )
target_link_libraries( ${PARENT_DIR} ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Comment: I would up having to do this to change the executable name: `add_executable( ${PARENT_DIR} ${PARENT_DIR}.cpp )`

Answer (score 0):

Create `CMakeLists.txt` for each subproject:

```
.
├── build
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── SubProjectA
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── SubProjectA.cpp
└── SubProjectB
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── SubProjectB.cpp
```

with the following content:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)

get_filename_component(PROJECT_NAME "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" NAME)
project("${PROJECT_NAME}")

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

set(PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")
set(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
set(SUB_PROJECT_SRC "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.cpp")
add_executable("${PROJECT_NAME}" ${SUB_PROJECT_SRC})
target_link_libraries("${PROJECT_NAME}" ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

In the main `CMakeLists.txt` include the subproject directories:

```
add_subdirectory(SubProjectA)
add_subdirectory(SubProjectB)
```

The method of getting project name from the current directory is taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12345018/1646322) answer.